# How include header file with cuda constants in any files

Tags: c++, cuda, constants

I have header file with this constants

```
__constant__ er_t SERIES_PREC;
__constant__ er_t ONE;
__constant__ er_t HALF;
```

I can't include this header file in any *.cu files - error linkin.
How can i use constant memory in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to reproduce the issue, I did not have any issue with the following:

header file:

```
#pragma once

__constant__ int mystuff ;
__constant__ int othersuff ;

__global__ void f(int* val);
__global__ void g(int* val);
```

First .cu file:

```
#include "constants.cuh"
__global__ void f(int* val) { *val = mystuff ; }
```

Second .cu file:

```
#include "constants.cuh"
__global__ void g(int* val) { *val = mystuff ; }
```

Main .cu file:

```
#include "constants.cuh"
int main()
{
    int* g_out ;
    cudaMalloc ((void**)&g_out, sizeof(int));

    f<<<1,1>>>(g_out);
    g<<<1,1>>>(g_out);
    ....
```

With no issue (CUDA 7.5, Visual Studio 2012). Maybe there is something with your er_t structure which is not accepted by the compiler. Does it have any initializer or field that may raises warning/error messages ?

Comment: Does it answer your question ?

Comment: nope, but it's give me awesome idea and now i can use constant memory all where i need